# Git Data backup from temp filder to a new disk (Disk3)

Tags: linux, git

Hey guys I am new to this Git and Linux..please can you let me know, how to copy data backup (here is backup.tar) to a new disk, as my root directory is showing 100%.

my backup path is : /opt/gitlab-6.5.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/tmp/backups$ls
               1419371767_gitlab_backup.tar  1428271073_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419458174_gitlab_backup.tar  1428357490_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419544598_gitlab_backup.tar  1428443884_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419631012_gitlab_backup.tar  1428530316_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419717436_gitlab_backup.tar  1428616692_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419803830_gitlab_backup.tar  1428703211_gitlab_backup.tar
               1419890198_gitlab_backup.tar  1428789555_gitlab_backup.tar

```
 Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/server4--vg-root  451G  427G  1.2G 100% /
 none                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 udev                          1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
 tmpfs                         376M 1016K  375M   1% /run
 none                           50M     0   50M   0% /run/lock
 none                          1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
 none                          100M  4.0K  100M   1% /run/user
 /dev/sdb1                     236M   65M  159M  29% /boot
 /dev/sda1                     917G  340G  531G  39% /mnt/disk2
 /dev/sdc1                     917G   75M  871G   1% /mnt/disk3
```

How do copy to disk3 and remove the backup from the old drive.

Comment: `mv /opt/gitlab-6.5.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/tmp/backups/*backup.tar /mnt/disk3/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downvoted because it's not a question about git per se, rather a question about Linux...

Anyway, use the `mv` command to move (or rename) files from one place to another.  Or use the `cp` command to copy them then `rm` to delete.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/758119-moving-files-linux-commands-file-managers) for more help on how to move files around.

Comment: @Gavin..thankx alot. I have moved almost 300GB data.